# Vue/Typescript: Checked is not a property on HTMLInputElement type

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a method that handles a box check but I am getting an issue with `target` on the event type.

```
    <input
        @change="$emit('change', $event.target.checked)"
        @keyup.enter="boxCheck($event)"
        :checked="checked"
        ref="test-input"
        type="checkbox"
   />
////
    boxCheck($event: HTMLInputElement) {
      if ($event?.target?.checked) {
        $event.target.checked = !$event.target.checked;
        this.$emit('change', $event.target.checked);
      }
    },
```

my error is `Property 'target' does not exist on type 'HTMLInputElement` but I thought only HTMLInputElement could be used for this.

Comment: Please show how this function is being used. You are likely not passing an HTMLInputElement to your function but rather an Event corresponding to a user action.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy just updated with the usage in the template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `boxCheck` method is receiving an `Event` not an `HTMLInputElement`. You can derive the type of the element based on your usage by casting the target within the method, such as below:

```
boxCheck($event: Event) {
  const el = $event.target as HTMLInputElement

  // el.checked now holds reference to what you need
}
```